# Twilio VoiceResponse speaker volume (loudness)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is there any way to adjust/set the volume (loudness) of the VoiceResponse?
I can hardly hear the voice response when I'm outdoors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I assume you mean the voice from the [`<Say>` TwiML verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) when reading out text to speech.

There is no way to adjust the volume, the intention is that it is at a normal speaking volume. Perhaps when outside you need to adjust the volume of your phone?

Comment: That's unfortunate. I don't have hardware control over the phone that I'm using. Is this on the road map at all or could I put in a feature request for this?

Comment: Hey, so this isn't on a roadmap at the moment. I'm not sure how this would work either, you wouldn't be able to tell whether someone was inside or outside so setting the volume might be too loud for some or too quiet for others. That's why, in my opinion, it's best left in the hands of the person or their device.

Comment: I agree that probably most of the time it'd be hard to tell whether someone was inside or outside or need the volume to be louder or not. I guess I'm in a special situation where I know for sure my user will be outside with lots of background noise. It would be nice to have the option to adjust the volume. The default value for the setting could just be what it is right now.

Comment: I appreciate your situation and I've raised it with the team internally, it's just not a high priority feature for us right now as it is quite a specific case that you have. There's not much more I can do for now I'm afraid.

Comment: I have the same issue - I have a voice prompt on a call box to a building. The voice comes through barely audible and if there's any noise on the street, it's impossible to hear, much less decipher the message. Would be nice to be able to bump the volume of the speaker.

Comment: Could you, as suggested in another answer, record the audio you need at a louder volume and play that instead of using text to speech?

Comment: I am really confused by the absence of this seemingly incredibly basic feature. I can barely hear the voice, even indoors in silence, and it's not a problem on my end since I don't have any issue with any other phone calls I receive from non-Twilio sources. What gives? How on earth can the volume not be customizable? It's literally just multiplying the audio signal by a constant.

Comment: @RadonRosborough Check Sam's answer on this question too. That might help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using amazon polly to synthesize your speech with SSML tags and have it return a .wav or .mp3 for the Play tag. You can then invoke the x-loud tag like this for example:

```
please press <prosody volume="x-loud" rate="slow">two</prosody> now
```

Try with Joanna's voice.